# PHP setcookie() strange behaviour

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

quys, I've got a trouble with my PHP application.

I have 2 pages for signing in and signing up. Both pages use common `cookies` class. Everything works fine, except one thing: `setcookie()` works only on `/signin` page (cookie value goes to the database, and cookie 'rwt' appears).

On signup page cookie value goes to the database, but `setcookie()` doesn't work.

Please, help.

P.S. That's the only problem, everything works on localhost, but not on production domain

P.P.S `$DBH` is PDO variable, which contains correct database information.

**Signin page**

```
$cookie = new Cookies($DBH);
 ........

if ($signin->remember=="yes") {
    $cookie->account_set($signin->user);
}
```

**Signup page**

```
  $cookie = new Cookies($DBH);
   .........
   ........

if ($signup->check_availability()) {

    $signup->save();

    $cookie->account_set($signup->user);

    header("Location:/");

} else {
    $msgText = "This username already exists";
    echo "<div class=\"orangeMsg\">$msgText</div>";
}
```

class `cookies`

```
 class Cookies
        {
            private $_DBH, $cookie_domain;  
            function __construct(PDO $DBH)
            {
                $this->_DBH=$DBH;
                $this->cookie_domain=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

            }
            public function account_set($value)
            {
                $cookie_value=uniquestr();
                // function from common.func.php
                $this->_DBH->query("UPDATE accounts SET cookie='$cookie_value' WHERE user='$value'");
                setcookie('rwt', $cookie_value, time()+60*60*24*7 , '/', $this->cookie_domain);
            }
            public function account_unset($value)
            {
                if (isset($_COOKIE['rwt'])) {
                    $cookie_value=$_COOKIE['rwt'];
                    setcookie("rwt", $cookie_value, time()-2592000, '/', $this->cookie_domain);
                    $this->_DBH->query("UPDATE accounts SET cookie=DEFAULT WHERE user='$value'");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***SOLUTION***

It was a mistake in my code, it's really weird that it worked on local server.

***MISTAKE EXPLANATION***

I had `if () {..}` and `if () {..} else {..}` blocks of logic related to the signing up process. That's stupid, but I expected them to be related to each other.

> Changing logic to `if () {..} elseif () {..} else {..}` has solved the
>   problem

I apologize for such lame mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You should *always* call `exit` directly after a `header('Location: ...')` call. Otherwise your script will continue running until the end, probably with some unexpected behavior as the result.

My guess is that you are in some way unsetting the cookie later on in the signup script.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is, that the combination of setting a cookie and sending a HTTP reply other than `200 OK` is prone to be troublesome. It might easily be, that your approach will work with some browsers, but not with others. You can improve the chances of this working by using `setcookie()` **before** `header('Location ...')`, (as some browsers seem to stop interpreting the headers if they encounter the `Location` header) but this is still no guarantee.

A workaround would be to redirect to your target location with a one-time GET parameter and set the cookie there.

Comment: It works on local virtual domain perfectly, that's why asked for a help